# Content-wise not page-wise pdf comparison library

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm looking for a library that I can use in a C# windows application for comparing PDF files. There are a lot of tools that I have seen for doing page-wise pdf comparison (e.g., http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/pdf-content-comparer). However, I want content-wise comparison. That means that if content is added or removed that will cause everything after the change to be shiffted, then I do not want the shifted content to be considered as changed.

One option is to extract the text from the pdf files and then doing a text comparison using an algorithm like the one proposed by Eugene W. Myers in his paper "An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variation". However, I wonder if there is a tool or library that I can use in C# to do this? Ideally, the tool will show the entire original document and highlight the changes. The tool will also detect other content changes like image changes.

Thanks.

Comment: What you want is rather precise for a library. If you wanted an application or GUI component, that I could understand, but a library is a little much. Are you sure you are asking for the right thing?

Answer (score 2):

A commercial option is DocsCorp compareDocs SDK (also known as DocuComp) http://www.docscorp.com/public/products/publicProductsDocuCompServer.cfm

It is a content based comparison solution. For example shifting of content due to insertion of a new paragraph will not cause all subsequent text to be considered 'changed'. The inserted paragraph will be marked as 'inserted' while the subsequent text will still be considered 'same'.

PDF to PDF comparison with output as single PDF. Changes are shown as annotations (insertions shown as underlined text, deletes are represented by PDF comments (yellow sticky notes) anchored to the point the deletion took place). Output can be a single PDF illustrating the changes. This is based on the modified PDF OR it can show a side by side view representing both PDF's in one PDF.

The comparison is text based only. It does not currently attempt to show changes in images or other graphical elements in PDF's.

For full disclosure I am employed and part own this company. My position is R&D VP.

Regards
Shane